# How to clone from Gitlab on the same server?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

## What I want to achieve

The gitlab runner is running on the same server as gitlab, which also runs on the same project the application is running (budget).

When master is updated I simply want to deploy the application locally, its a PHP application and it's user composer. So a important fact is that I cant have different git urls. It has to be *git@gitlab.xxx.xxx:project/repo.git* everywhere.

## The problem

When cloning locally I can't seem to access the repo.

```
Cloning into 'test'...
The authenticity of host 'gitlab.xxx.xxx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is qw:qw:qw:qw:qw:qw:qw:qw:qw.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? 
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

A clone from my dev machine works though, my key is added to the user that has rights to the project in gitlab:

```
git clone 'git@gitlab.xxx.xxx:project/repo.git'
```

## What i've tried

1. The user that does the clone is the gitlab runner, I did generate a ssh key and added it to the project.
2. Tried to check if the key was actually used by the agent `ssh-add -l`, but it seems my knowledge is too limited since that results in:
   `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.` *Maybe because i used `su gitlab-runner`?*
3. ... dead in the water, I feel like it has something to do with the way ssh works and what it's causing when running it on the same server. Like i said, im using a dependency manager that doesnt allow env variables for things such as a repo for a specific package, so im stuck with using the `git@gitlab...` url both on the server and my dev machine.

Comment: Have you ever found an answer to your problem? I am strugling with the same thing

Comment: I've also tried running git clone from within the docker, but it also didn't work.